# Definition of Bayesian network

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, graphical-model, bayesian-network

In this [PDF](http://people.csail.mit.edu/yks/documents/classes/mlbook/pdf/chapter2.pdf), page 5 says:

> Given a set of functions $f(x_i,pa(x_i))$ non-negative and sum to 1,
>   we define a joint probability as follow: $$p(x_1,\dots, x_n)=\prod_i
>  f(x_i,pa(x_i))$$ [...] what is the relationship between the
>   conditional probability $p(x_i|pa(x_i))$ and $f(x_i,pa(x_i))$, a
>   function with has the properties of a conditional function but it is
>   arbitrary? As will see, this function is in the fact one and same.
>   That is, under the definition of joint probability, the function
>   $f(x_i,pa(x_i))$ is $p(x_i|pa(x_i))$.

How can it go from $f(x_i,pa(x_i))$ to $p(x_i|pa(x_i))$ and state that it is the only possible function that can be assigned to $f(x_i,pa(x_i))$?

Comment: The link is 403.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author of the book explains in Section 2.1.3 why, given the particular constraints  on the function $f(x_i, pa(x_i))$, one can view the function $f(x_i, pa(x_i))$ as equivalent to the conditional probability $P(x_i | pa(x_i))$.  This equivalence only holds because of the particular property of the function and the structure of the graphical model.